# Custom rx Func1 for retrofit response code handling

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am new in rxjava, so please don't be strict...

I have request lice next one:

```
Observable<Login>login(String l, String p){
        return api.loginUser(l,p)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(new Func1<Response<Login>, Observable<? extends Login>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends Login> call(Response<Login> r) {
                        switch (r.code()){
                            case 200:
                                requestOk(r);
                                break;
                            case 202:
                                //need to Repeat
                                login.timeout(2000,TimeUnit.Milliseconds);
                                break;
                            default:
                                //
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

Observable<Login> requestOk(final Response<Login> r){
            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Login>(){
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Login> subscriber) {
                    if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) return;
                    subscriber.onNext(r.body());
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            });
        }
```

It works ok. But there will be a lot of other requests where I need to check request code in case of repeat.

So I was trying to create custom Func1 - universal for all request:

```
private <T>Func1<? super Response<T>, ? extends Observable<? extends T>> customFunc(final Observable<T> o) {
        return new Func1<Response<T>, Observable<? extends T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<? extends T> call(Response<T> r) {
                switch (r.code()){
                    case 200:
                        //
                        break;
                    case 202:
                        //need to Repeat
                        return o.timeout(2000,TimeUnit.Milliseconds);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //
                }
            };
        };
    }
```

I am stuck with putting current observable from login observable into customFunc.

I believe there must be some other, easier and correct way how to do this.
Will be glad any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Transformer` in order to create a generic status code verifier:

```
class StatusCodeVerifierTransformer<T> implements Observable.Transformer<Response<T>, T> {

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<Response<T>> responseObservable) {
        return responseObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Response<T>, Observable<T>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<T> call(Response<T> loginResponse) {
                switch (loginResponse.code()) {
                    case 200:
                        return Observable.just(loginResponse.body());
                    case 202:
                        //need to Repeat
                        return Observable.error(new Status202Exception());
                    default:
                        return Observable.error(new Exception("unknown error"));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

this transformer will take any `Observable` of `Response<T>` and will transform it to `Observable` of `T`, that emits errors according to your strategy.
Then use it with `compose()` operator:

```
  Observable<Login> login(String l, String p) {
    return api.loginUser(l, p)
            .compose(new StatusCodeVerifierTransformer<>())
   }
```

Now you have an `Observable` that will emit `onError` with your desired exception according to your status code handling.

Now, you can retry on error like with any `Observable` with `retry` operator, for instance like this:

```
 api.loginUser(l, p)
            .compose(new StatusCodeVerifierTransformer<>())
            .retry(new Func2<Integer, Throwable, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Integer retryCount, Throwable throwable) {
                    return throwable instanceof Login202Exception && retryCount < MAX_RETRY;
                }
            })
```

**BTW**, some comments:

requestOk - you definitely don't need to create `Observable` for emitting specific value once, just use the `just()` operator, like in the `StatusCodeVerifierTransformer` example. (or for any other synchronize operation, you have plenty of operators like `fromCallable()`, `just()`, `from()`)
Generally, `create()` is not a safe method of creating an `Observable` anymore.