# Handling response with no body with Retrofit2 and rxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a WS which returns 200 with no body if successful
or 420 with json in error body is unsuccessful

Return type is

```
Observable<Response<Void>>
```

For some reason in case of error with 420 code `onNext(Response<Void> value)` is called instead of `onError(Throwable e)` which is being called for any other unsuccessful requests.

Why only in this case onNext instead of onError is called? It is possible to call onError if the request didn't returned 200?

Comment: Try Observable<Void> instead of Observable<Response<Void>>

Comment: Is I use Observable<Void> I get nullpointer in onError(Throwable e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly the expected behavior when using `Response`, any kind of status code is encapsulated as a `Response` object, and emitted with `onNext()`. while any kind of other exception (network error/ parsing error/some other configuration error) will be delivered as Exception in `onError()`.

With the bare object apprach (`Observable<T>`/`Observable<Void>`), for any other situation other than got response from server and the response was parsed successfully, you will get `onError()`.

in case of RxJava2, `Observable<Void>` is no longer valid, as null cannot be emitted (not allowed anymore with RxJava2), instead you should use `Completable`.

With the `Response`, you can wrap your one Error handler for instance for specific server error codes. (you can see an example at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424141/3903847))

In addition, there is also `Result` type that encapsulate any error kind and a `Response` if any.

Comment: If I use Observable<Void> and receive 200 with no body, I get a nullpointer instead of onNext call

Comment: As rxJava2 doesn't support null values, I need to use Response<Void> and make error handling in onNext

Comment: yes, you're right, you should use Completable with RxJava2, answer updated.

Comment: Tried different approaches and using Completable is the most suitable for my case.